# Is it bad practice to put all information into lists instead of class inheritance in OOP?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, terminology

Using lists would save many lines of code, but wouldn't it kill the very idea behind OOP? As it would make more sense to implement it using functional programming.

An example of using lists in Python:

```
class Pets:

    def printlist(self, petslist):
        for pet in petslist:
            print pet[0]+ " is a "+pet[1]

pet = Pets()
pet.printlist([('parrot','bird'),('snake','reptile'),('dog','mammal')])is a "+pet[1]
```

An example of using class inheritance:

```
class Pets:
        def __init__(self, pet, petclass):
                self.petclass=petclass
                self.pet=pet

        def printlist(self):
                print self.pet+" is a  "+self.petclass

class Dog(Pets):
        def __init__(self):
                Pets.__init__(self, "dog", "mammal")

class Parrot(Pets):
        def __init__(self):
                Pets.__init__(self, "parrot", "bird")

class Snake(Pets):
        def __init__(self):
                Pets.__init__(self, "snake", "reptile")

x = Dog()
x.printlist()

y = Parrot()
y.printlist()

z = Snake()
z.printlist()
```

Also, what if the list is too big to be handled by inheritance? Isn't it much easier to use lists that can be imported from a text file or something?

Does that make OOP useless in such cases? or is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think this is a bad practice. There is no validation that the list has two strings, or even that it contains strings at all. Suppose I pass a list of three strings, or one, or the empty list? What then?

But aside from that, you are forgoing most of the advantages of OOP. These classes are just names with no behavior associated with them. There's no notion of inheritance, and no clear way to associate other information with the objects. Would you store it in additional positions in the list? There's also no information hiding, so there's no way to ensure any invariants. Anyone who has access to the lists could change them at any time.

You might just as well store strings like "snake is a reptile", "dog is a mammal", and "parrot is a bird" instead of using lists.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've probably used a bad example but I've got your point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question one gets when trying to decide on the purpose of the object.
If the object is to 'Store' some data Versus the object has to behave in a specific way.

In your example above, if your intention is only to store the data, and print them (using a standard method), use 'list'.
That will suffice the purpose.

On the other hand, if you want each of the 'variety' to **behave** differently, use classes.

```
class Pet:
    def makeSound(self, args):
        None

class Dog(Pet):
    def makeSound(self, args):
        'Specific behaviour ONLY for Dogs.

class Parrot(Pet):
    def makeSound(self, args):
        'Specific behaviour ONLY for Parrots.
```

You might consider 'Classes' if you wanted to implement 'printlist' differently for each variety of Pet.